# Different significance in GLMM interactions

Tags: statistical-significance, interaction, glmm, predictor

I am confused about different significance results obtained in GLMM's.

First, my set of relevant variables:

```
R - a binary response variable

C1, C2, C3, C4, and W - a set of continuous covariates

B1, B2, B3 - a set of binary covariates
```

I checked for correlation and they all have values way lower than 0.50 - which is the threshold I defined.

Then I started to build some GLMM, because I wanted to include individuals as random effect.

The first one is quite simple; I just wanted to check the effect of the continuous variables, so:

```
GLMM1 <- R ~ C1 + C2 + C3 + C4 + (1|ID)
```

For this model, I obtained C1, C3 and C4 variables with statistical significance.

Then I ran another model, to check how a binary variable was interaction with the continuous variable:

```
GLMM2 <- R ~ B1*C1 + B1*C2 + B1*C3 + B1*C4 + (1|ID)
```

However, in this case, all interactions were significant and B1 individually as well, but C1 was not. My first question: shouldn't C1 be significant as well? Since it was significant in the simplest.

Another model:

```
GLMM3 <- R ~ W*C1 + W*C2 + W*C3 + W*C4 + (1|ID)
```

Here, all interactions were significant as well but C4 individually was not significant. Plus, C2 was significant although it was not in GlMM1 and 2.

So, my main question is why is the significance of covariates individually (without interaction) changing from model to model? Since the dataset is exactly the same, shouldn't this simpler variables have the same meaning?

Does anyone know a website/book/etc. that explains this issue?

Comment: It is common. Given covariates are not orthogonal (corr < 0.5 is not enough), it is not surprise that different combinations of covariates can generated inconsistent results.

Comment: @a_statistician, do you mean I should reduce the correlation threshold?

Comment: I mean: Under condition that all corr = 0, the estimate of the regression coefficients will not change regardless which other covariates in the model. Otherwise, the other variables in the model will effect the estimate of the regression coefficients.